# Memory error when trying LOESS prediction with standard errors

Tags: r, out-of-memory, smoothing, loess

If I try to predict standard errors using my LOESS model trained on 30000 observations I get a memory error saying `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.7 Gb`. However, I really need this for plotting. Sadly, I need to use LOESS with `span=1` so changing method or this parameter is not an option. How can I prevent the code from raising an error?

I've created a MWE below:

```
x <- seq(0, 30000)
df <- as.data.frame(x)
df$y <- 1 - df$x*(1/30000)

loess_mod <- loess(y ~ x, df)
loess_pred <- predict(loess_mod, x, se=FALSE) # works fine
loess_pred <- predict(loess_mod, x, se=TRUE) # crash with memory error ("Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.7 Gb")
```

Comment: No solution, but your example runs on a 32GB RAM desktop (Linux 64 bits). The calculation used ~20GB of RAM.